# How do you install Python3 modules so that they will be usable in the terminal and Pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, module

I don't fully understand the system of module usage in Python yet.

I know how to install modules in the terminal, and how to install them using the interpreter section of Pycharm, but I don't understand the difference of installing either way, and how to install to a singular location which will enable usage of the module universally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by installing through terminal using pip3 that the modules were usable in the shell as well as Pycharm